# Garbage collector can clear part of my data?

Tags: java, spring, heroku

In my Java application, which provides APIs to my clients, I created an authorization system between users, entities, web services and profile types.

All these permissions are saved in a table at the launch of the application, then updated as soon as I create a new permission, or a new web service, or a new profile

Declare class :

```
@Component("accessChecker")
@Scope("singleton")
public class AccessChecker {
```

Constructor :

```
 HashMap<String, List<Permission>> permissions = new HashMap<String, List<Permission>>();


public AccessChecker(PermissionRepository permissionRepository, WebServiceRepository webServiceRepository,
                     ProfilRepository profilRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
    super();
    this.permissionRepository = permissionRepository;
    this.webServiceRepository = webServiceRepository;
    this.profilRepository = profilRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;

    this.updatePermissions();
}
```

Method in the same classe to load data !

```
public void updatePermissions() {
    log.info("**** DEBUT MISE A JOUR DES PERMISSIONS");
    List<Permission> permissionsTmp = permissionRepository.findAllWithEagerRelationships();

    // clear permissions
    this.permissions = new HashMap<String, List<Permission>>();

    // load all permissions
    for (Permission permission : permissionsTmp) {
        Profil profil = profilRepository.findOne(permission.getProfil().getId());
....
```

The problem I'm having lately is that I feel like I'm losing some of the content from time to time. Sometimes a client calls me saying that he or she has no access to data. By reloading permissions by creating a permission. Once done, everything seems to be in order

Do you have any idea why I'm losing this data ?

My app is deployed on Heroku

Comment: you should code your data so that you are saving info to txt files or such, an exterior source, or they will be erased by GarbageCollecter no matter what. You can then call info from your txt file when needed.

Comment: gc only frees memory from data if there is no more reference to the data.

Comment: maybe you shoul read something about thread safety and synchronization.

Comment: Each web service call consults this object

Comment: @tomas adding information : I am not losing all data of my object, only a part.. 
it's a mystery to me

Comment: for me it looks like a problem with your synchronization... give it a try ;-)

Comment: @tomas  I don't know what is the synchronization, I will look. Have you a good link?

Comment: this is fundamental in java programming...google for "java memory modell" or "java thread safety"

Comment: @Tomas, I will look thanks

Comment: @Tomas I use only thread, I don't think the problem is synchronize or thread

Comment: Are you running the app on more than one dyno? In any case, the dyno/process will restart every 24-hours, so any state must be stored externally (like in a database).

Comment: @codefinger Yes I use 1 dyno. Each restart reload my HashMap permission

Comment: If you run your app on heroku and the dyno restart all your data will be reset because the app also restarts. You have to use a database or external file storage.

Comment: @SimonFranzen I understand what you say, but my permission data are reload at each restart of application

Comment: Ok got it. I am just interested what is your data storage and where do you load it. Is this working?

Comment: @SimonFranzen
My data is stored in a Postgresql database, and loaded into my hashmao at startup. Everything works, but sometimes I feel that my hashmap loses values, but not all